# OAuth Mandrill for OmniAuth

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, omniauth

I would want integrate Mandrill connection in our solution with OAuth. 
I followed a instructions for build application on Mandrill UI, but Mandrill give only client ID, without client SECRET.

So, I try to define a provider in `OmniAuth::Builder`but it doesn't works.
My question is, do you think is possible to use OmniAuth authentication system for Mandrill OAuth (which not delivery client SECRET) ?

Thanks